# Problem with BCP writing to .txt file from SQL

Tags: sql, bcp

Im using Sql2008 trying to run this BCP command but it never creates the file.

```
-- Export query
  DECLARE @qry2 VARCHAR(1000)
  SET @qry2 = 'SELECT * FROM @SkippedProductsTable'

  -- Folder we will be putting the file in         
  DECLARE @incomingfolder VARCHAR(1000)
  SET @incomingfolder = 'c:\Logs'

  DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(2000)
  SET @bcpCommand = 'bcp "'+@qry2+'" queryout "'+@incomingfolder+'\SkippedProducts-'+CAST(@StoreMatchCode AS VARCHAR)+'-'+'.txt" -c -T'

  PRINT @bcpCommand
  EXEC MASTER..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand, no_output
```

The created command looks like:

```
bcp "SELECT * FROM @SkippedProductsTable" queryout "c:\Logs\SkippedProducts-1330-.txt" -c -T
```

Can anyone suggest what could be going wrong? I've never used BCP before and not really sure where to start looking.

As a start I know that the folder deffinately exists at that location

Comment: Did you actually assign that first line to `@Bcpcommand` variable?

Comment: And don't forget that's a path on the server

Comment: Yea the first line is actually a print of what comes from the @bcpCommand Variable   also the path for the folder im putting the file in does exist on the server

Comment: I added more details of the code im using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is the `SELECT`.

You are `SELECT`ing from a table variable that is not declared in the query, so there's nothing for BCP to do.

Table variables only persist for the context they are called in, so even if you have one in a query, and you have dynamic sql or a subproc within that first query, they won't be able to see the table variable.

[See this for more info.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/sqltools/thread/02337dd5-5cfd-40d8-b529-12dc557d6a7e)